# C# Locking Vault Object

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Does the following code work well for locking simple objects?

If so why is it not more used / how can it be improved? If not why not?

```
public class Vault<T>
{
    private object key = new object();
    private T _Item;

    public Vault() { }

    public Vault(T Deposit)
    {
        Set(Deposit);
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            return _Item;
        }
    }
    public void Set(T Deposit)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            _Item = Deposit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reality is that locking for single property is rarely needed (especially for reference types, there is some value for value types in your code). When you need to lock for multiple field updates it is pretty much always one-off case and generic helper would not help :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the one benefit it could be is in situations where you need a memory barrier, making sure multiple threads all have the current value

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes,... unfortunately the drawback of suggested code is now you have that value in an instance of another reference type and hence you have to make sure that the reference does not change - back to locking the reference to `Vault<T>` in original class :) ... and making it `struct` not going to make things any better from "is this code correct" point of view.

Comment: I figured it might have some use in say a downloader thread, that's attempting to download some file. IsActive, %Complete, etc might change at anytime but they all tend to change independent to one another.

Comment: The problem is that it still doesn't guarantee operations like increment and decrement (any read-modify-write operation) will be atomic,  that is that another thread doesn't modify it between read and write. It's useful for a small subset of issues but isn't a one size fits all solution.

Comment: You should consider a concurrent approach by passing messages (actions) to a thread which handles the value. Other threads will either read from that thread or write to it. That way you don't need a lock and just needs pass the messages around. You could ex. cache the value and just take the cached value if there has been no changes, to avoid accessing the thread every time you use the value. It's a bit complex, but if you have a large application that requires good performance then less locking is better.

Answer (score 0):

**Does the following code work well for locking simple objects?**
The answer is Yes.

lock statement is a C# syntactic sugar for Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit 
At the moment of this answer you can see the this class is not obsolete, maybe that can answer your question: **so why is it not more used** .For reference you can see [MSDN Monitor class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx). The overhead of a lock statement is 20ns

Just a couple of comments, if inside of your lock statement an Exception is thrown that can be harmfull if you don't consider a try-catch surrounding the lock, a solution for a complex case is a "rollback". On the below sample you can lose money if an exception is thrown.

```
  public void Set(T Deposit)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            _Item -= Deposit/x;  x can take the value of zero
        }
    }
```

For your improvements consider a try-catch 
to avoid that problem.

In case you want to use Monitor class directly Monitor.Enter has an extra parameter ref bool lockTaken that can be useful, the correct pattern to use it is (which is exactly how C# 4.0 translates a lock statement)

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
  Monitor.Enter (_locker, ref lockTaken);
  // Do your stuff...
}
finally { if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit (_locker); }
```

You can read more about lock here [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking)